# Run a separate application on secondary monitor

Tags: android

Android supports rendering apps to secondary screen (added in 4.2), but is it possible to run one application on a primary monitor and another application on secondary monitor?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you mean by "run an application" with respect to external displays. Are you asking "can I write an app that shows content on an external display, without affecting the primary display"? Are you asking "can I launch a third-party app and shove its contents into an external display"? Are you asking "can I write a custom ROM that allows the user to use multiple displays the way they can in a desktop OS"? Are you asking something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare, what i want to do is to launch a secondary app (two apps simultaneously), they shall be both in active state, e.g. the primary app handles touch events from display, while the secondary app which is being displayed on the secondary display handles hardware buttons e.g. joystick. At first I consider Android API capabilities, but I think some changes to AOSP may be required.

Comment: Unless you are the author of the secondary app, what you want is not possible via the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am the author of the secondary app. The exact use case is to have the primary app as a launcher (I want to replace the system one), upon a click on the app icon in launcher grid, the secondary app shall be launched on the secondary monitor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android SDK ships with a `Presentation` class that allows the foreground activity to display alternate content on an external display. This was built with an eye towards "second screen" apps, where you might be watching a movie on the external display and using the touchscreen to control playback, chat with friends, etc. The limitation of `Presentation` is that it is effectively a `Dialog`, and therefore only works when driven by the foreground activity.

However, it is possible, using `WindowManager`, to have a `Service` display content on an external display. I have [a `PresentationService` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation#usage-presentationservice) that demonstrates the technique and simplifies its use. Given a `Display` object representing the external display (e.g., `DisplayManager`), you can have `WindowManager` direct content to that `Display`, from some `View` that you inflate or otherwise create.

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2014 CommonsWare, LLC

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
  not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
  a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
 */

package com.commonsware.cwac.preso;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 * A service that drives a presentation from the background. Use this when
 * presentations need to span activities or when they should be occurring even
 * if the app's UI has moved to the background.
 *
 * This is an abstract class -- create a subclass and override getThemeId() and
 * buildPresoView().
 */
public abstract class PresentationService extends Service implements
    PresentationHelper.Listener {
  /**
   * @return the theme to use for driving the resources used by
   * this presentation
   */
  protected abstract int getThemeId();

  /**
   * Override this to provide the UI that goes into the presentation.
   * This works somewhat like a fragment's onCreateView().
   *
   * @param ctxt a Context, in case you need one, but note that it will
   *            <i>not</i> be an activity
   * @param inflater a LayoutInflater, in case you need one for creating
   *                 the UI
   * @return the View that should be shown on the external display
   */
  protected abstract View buildPresoView(Context ctxt,
                                         LayoutInflater inflater);

  private WindowManager wm=null;
  private View presoView=null;
  private PresentationHelper helper=null;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return(null);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    helper=new PresentationHelper(this, this);
    helper.onResume();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    helper.onPause();

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void showPreso(Display display) {
    Context presoContext=createPresoContext(display);
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(presoContext);

    wm=
        (WindowManager)presoContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    presoView=buildPresoView(presoContext, inflater);
    wm.addView(presoView, buildLayoutParams());
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void clearPreso(boolean switchToInline) {
    if (presoView != null) {
      try {
        wm.removeView(presoView);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // probably the window is gone, don't worry, be
        // happy
      }
    }

    presoView=null;
  }

  protected WindowManager.LayoutParams buildLayoutParams() {
    return(new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                                          0, PixelFormat.OPAQUE));
  }

  private Context createPresoContext(Display display) {
    Context displayContext=createDisplayContext(display);
    final WindowManager wm=
        (WindowManager)displayContext.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    return(new ContextThemeWrapper(displayContext, getThemeId()) {
      @Override
      public Object getSystemService(String name) {
        if (Context.WINDOW_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
          return(wm);
        }

        return(super.getSystemService(name));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

(source from [v0.4.6](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation/blob/v0.4.6/presentation/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/preso/PresentationService.java))

Comment: I think that's the only option without a deep customisation of AOSP. So it would a be a single app with various services.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Comment: @Taras: The two apps can be separate. There is nothing that requires the app with the `PresentationService` have anything in the foreground, IIRC. It's been a while since I played with this.

Comment: oh.. got it! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Android Oreo enabled feature to launch application in secondary screen.

Step1 : Need to enable **secondary_displays** feature in the AOSP level.

Step2 : Get **setLaunchDisplayId** In the application level .

Step3 : Via intent send activityOptions to your second activity.

Step4 : Finally,your application launch only in secondary screen.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0.html

Thank you

Comment: Picture in Picture is not secondary display. Granted you might be able to use as such.

Comment: @Naren is it possible to achieve this for a third party app to launch on a secondary screen on Android 11+ ? Like, for example to get launch intent for Instagram and set display id as external display's display id.?