# Launch another application in secondary screen in Android_O

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, presentation, multiscreen

Device have two screens.In the first screen normal UI(launcher app),and in the second screen to launch google maps app.

How can we launch another application secondary screen.

```
Service class:
@Override
protected View buildPresoView(Context ctxt, LayoutInflater inflater) {
View topView = new View(this);
  topView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("abc.abc.abc");
  startActivity(i);
      }
  });

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display, null,false);    

    return(topView);
   //return(contentView);
  }
 PresentationHelper:
 @Override
public void showPreso(Display display) {
Context presoContext=createPresoContext(display);
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(presoContext);
wm=(WindowManager)presoContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
presoView=buildPresoView(presoContext, inflater);
wm.addView(presoView, buildLayoutParams());
}
```

I have followed this link: 
   [Run a separate application on secondary monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567220/run-a-separate-application-on-secondary-monitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check presentation mode is enable or not in devices level (IN aosp).
If not add the following tag in device `.xml` file.

```
<feature name="android.software.activities_on_secondary_displays" />
```

Comment: now presentation mode is enabled using above flag.but application is not launching from one app to another

Comment: where this tag must to be added?