# Android API 19: How do you disable screen mirroring?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, multiple-monitors

I have a Android Device running KitKat (rooted) that has an HDMI input and an internal display. When I plug an external display into the HDMI it just appears to mirror what's on the internal display onto the external display. Is there a way to disable this and show two activities across the displays?

I've tried following this post: [Run a separate application on secondary monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567220/run-a-separate-application-on-secondary-monitor) and haven't had any luck.

UPDATE: I tried using `Developer Tools` --> `Simulate secondary display` and it's still mirroring there. I think there might be an OS setting that is causing the mirroring.

Comment: The technique that I outlined in my answer to the linked-to question definitely works, so there may be some issue with your specific hardware that is causing it to not work.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using your demo app and it's saying _You should see content on the secondary display_ on both screens

Comment: Is there any shell command to disable mirroring?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. `Presentation` should take precedence. You might want to step through the code and see if the `Presentation` is actually getting set up.

Comment: So I just noticed something interesting. Simulating a secondary mirrored until I unplugged the HDMI, then once I unplugged it your DEMO app was working perfectly. When I plugged the HDMI back in it was mirroring again.

Comment: If I had to guess, there is something afoot with your device, where it ignores the normal display stuff and always mirrors. That's not normal behavior, so you would need to start looking at device-specific or manufacturer-specific solutions (e.g., your aforementioned shell command to disable this forced mirroring).

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll have to contact them.